# Javascript: destructor or something like that

Tags: javascript

I've created this little object that's pretty handy when it comes to intervals and works pretty good as an animation frame, but it has this little thing about it. If the reference to the instance is lost, the interval keeps going.

```
function Interval(callback, interval){
    var timer = null;
    this.start = function(){
        if(!timer) timer = setInterval(callback, interval);
    };
    this.stop = function(){
        clearInterval(timer);
        timer = null;
    };
    this.changeSpeed = function(a){
        interval = a;
        this.stop();
        this.start();
    }
    this.destroy = function(){
        delete this;
    }
}
```

Obviously if javascript has no destruct method I can't track when to stop the interval, so I figured I should create a destroy method, but I'm not really sure if I can destroy the instance from within the object. It makes sense but... Any help is appreciated!

Comment: The question being, why would the reference to the instance be lost in the first place, and if it is lost, how will you reference the instance in this destroy method ?

Comment: @adeneo is right. So long as your code has a reference to an object, it won't be garbage collected. So if you have a reference, it wont be lost.

Comment: @adeneo well if someone was to ever use this and they decide unsetting the reference would stop the interval, they'd be really disappointed. Not like it's a big deal but it's just bugging me from the inside, you know what it's like, I guess.. :D

Comment: +1 for your(fake) pic.. nope.

Comment: Fake pic?? Really? My vote is already locked.

Comment: But if they remove the reference, how will you know what to destroy. I guess you could add a `create` method that stores references when something is created, but then the reference wouldn't be lost ?

Comment: Perhaps you could improve it by requiring the `callback` parameter to take a parameter that is a reference to the instance itself. Then at least if the callback keeps firing, it will always have a reference to it's source and could kill it. Also, I'd at least have `destroy` call `stop`.

Comment: Is there a badge awarded for profile views or something?

Comment: Wow @RakeshKR, now this is what I call a minor edit.

Comment: @MattBurland Thank you for the suggestion. It seems like I can't figure out how I'd pass that reference inside of the object and how it's going to affect the interval that's already running? Also I just added that `destroy` method to illustrate what I have in mind, not that it actually works

Comment: @Streppel what you mean? A dot makes a lot difference(like a pic)! haha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about doing something like this:

```
function Interval(callback, interval){
    var self = this;
    var timer = null;
    this.start = function(){
        if(!timer) timer = setInterval(function() {
            callback(self)
        }, interval);
    };
    this.stop = function(){
        clearInterval(timer);
        timer = null;
    };
    this.changeSpeed = function(a){
        interval = a;
        this.stop();
        this.start();
    }
    this.destroy = function(){
        this.stop();
    }
}
```

Now at least when the callback is called it will pass a reference to the your object and the callback will at least have a chance to stop it if they don't need it anymore.

The trick here is to use a closure to ensure you can still reference the object when the interval expires (hence the `self` variable).

So now I could do something like this:

```
var foo = new Interval(function(i) {
     // check if my interval is still needed
     if (dontNeedItAnymore) {
         i.destroy();        // or just .stop()
     }
     else {
         // do whatever
     }
}, 1000);

foo = null;       // whoops, lost the reference, but the callback will still be able to reference it
```

Comment: Ohh now I see what you mean. Well if there's no way to do it automatically then I guess this is as far as it can go. Thank you sir!

Comment: @Bergi: that was in the OP's code that I cut and pasted.